# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): [Answer] React Native Error while making XMLHttpRequest via device or emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> logging error like: Unhandled Promise Rejection with Error: Network Error

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error
Error: Network Error
    at createError (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:79490:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:79398:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:17902:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:17657:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:17484:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:17594:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:3480:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:2386:44)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:2156:17
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/3aab7ec1-40be-4c43-864c-6474a71b00c9:2348:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This error comes when your device or emulator is not connected to internet and trying to make XMLHttpRequest with axios or fetch via device or emulator.
Please make sure you are connected on the same network on both your machine and your device. Also reverify that your debugger is running on localhost.**